# Select from XML query

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am looking to   I’m not certain the syntax to reference the array field.  Please could someone assist me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @data XML = '--your--XML--here';

SELECT
    XC.value('(FLD[@NM="TOTAL POLICY PREM"])[1]', 'decimal(16,2)'),
    XC2.value('(./@NM)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    XC2.value('(ARRAYVALUE)[2]', 'varchar(20)')
FROM
    @data.nodes('/POLOUTPUTS') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY
    xc.nodes('FLDARRAY') AS XT2(XC2)
WHERE
    XC2.value('(./@NM)[1]', 'varchar(50)') = 'PAY PLAN POLI PREM ARR'
```

The first `.nodes()` call returns a list of XML fragments for each `<POLOUTPUTS>` element, from which you can the fetch the value of the `<FLD>` with the `TOTAL POLICY PREM` attribute value.

The second, nested `.nodes()` call returns a list of XML fragments for each `<FLDARRAY>` elements inside the `<POLOUTPUTS>` element - and from this, you can fetch the value of the `NM` attribute (for comparison in the `WHERE` clause), and the value of the second `<ARRAYVALUE>` element inside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @x xml = N'<POLOUTPUTS>
      <FLD NM="MAXIMUM DRIVER AGE">43.59</FLD>
............
      <FLD NM="RED MOUNTAIN SCORE MAX">735</FLD>
      <FLD NM="TOTAL POLICY PREM">1678.37</FLD>
      <FLD NM="VEH MIN BI IND" />
      <FLDARRAY NM="PAY PLAN DESCR ARR">
.............
        <ARRAYVALUE>0</ARRAYVALUE>
      </FLDARRAY>
      <FLDARRAY NM="PAY PLAN POLI PREM ARR">
        <ARRAYVALUE>1678.37</ARRAYVALUE>
        <ARRAYVALUE>1621.54</ARRAYVALUE>
        <ARRAYVALUE>1635.74</ARRAYVALUE>
...............
        <ARRAYVALUE>0</ARRAYVALUE>
    </FLDARRAY>
</POLOUTPUTS>'


select 
    @x.value('(POLOUTPUTS/FLD[@NM="TOTAL POLICY PREM"])[1]', 'decimal(9,2)'),
    @x.value('(POLOUTPUTS/FLDARRAY[@NM="PAY PLAN POLI PREM ARR"]/ARRAYVALUE[2])[1]', 'decimal(9,2)');
```

Comment: I appreciate it. Thank you.